# Android anchor ImageView left and top at (0, 0)

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to implement the Telegram like image zoom in and out animation in my app. Look at their source code I see the class `ClippingImageView` animate this effect by using a property animator. The problem is when I try applying this to my app my view `getLeft()` and `getTop()` was not at (0, 0). So `setTranslationX()` and `setTranslationY()` get the wrong number because `animationValues` was calculate at (0, 0).

Is there a way I can position the `View` at (0, 0) with the actual image content take up another part of the screen, like the top right corner?

**EDIT**

This is what I've tried so far, apparently this is just a part of Telegram source that I cloned to my app.
`animationValues` store the starting and ending value of the properties.

```
        animationValues[0][0] = animatingImageView.getScaleX();
        animationValues[0][1] = animatingImageView.getScaleY();
        animationValues[0][2] = animatingImageView.getTranslationX();
        animationValues[0][3] = animatingImageView.getTranslationY();
        animationValues[0][4] = clipHorizontal * object.scale;
        animationValues[0][5] = clipTop * object.scale;
        animationValues[0][6] = clipBottom * object.scale;
        animationValues[0][7] = animatingImageView.getRadius();

        animationValues[1][0] = scale;
        animationValues[1][1] = scale;
        animationValues[1][2] = xPos;
        animationValues[1][3] = yPos;
        animationValues[1][4] = 0;
        animationValues[1][5] = 0;
        animationValues[1][6] = 0;
        animationValues[1][7] = 0;
```

Then in `ClippingImageView.java`

```
public void setAnimationProgress(float progress) {
    animationProgress = progress;

    setScaleX(animationValues[0][0] + (animationValues[1][0] - animationValues[0][0]) * animationProgress);
    setScaleY(animationValues[0][1] + (animationValues[1][1] - animationValues[0][1]) * animationProgress);
    setTranslationX(animationValues[0][2] + (animationValues[1][2] - animationValues[0][2]) * animationProgress);
    setTranslationY(animationValues[0][3] + (animationValues[1][3] - animationValues[0][3]) * animationProgress);
    setClipHorizontal((int) (animationValues[0][4] + (animationValues[1][4] - animationValues[0][4]) * animationProgress));
    setClipTop((int) (animationValues[0][5] + (animationValues[1][5] - animationValues[0][5]) * animationProgress));
    setClipBottom((int) (animationValues[0][6] + (animationValues[1][6] - animationValues[0][6]) * animationProgress));
    setRadius((int) (animationValues[0][7] + (animationValues[1][7] - animationValues[0][7]) * animationProgress));

    invalidate();
}
```

I also notice that when I log the `animatingImageView.getMeasuredWidth()` and `animatingImageView.getMeasuredHeight()` they all give me 0. Is this just a dummy view for animation purpose?

Comment: Please share some code so we can see what you've already tried.